# How to decide which quantum device to use if a quantum algorithm is given?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, experimental-realization

I'm planning to write my master thesis in quantum computing. The subject of the thesis is to find out which attributes (properties, features) of quantum algorithms respectively their implementations (circuits) are important to decide which quantum device to use. Quantum devices differ in connectivity, number of qbits, gate fidelity etc. So what kind of attributes of the algorithms would be important? Number of swap-operations? Number of ancilla bits? Breadth? Depth? Entanglement depth? ...

Here an illustrative use case:

An user has some database (e.g. phone book) and some data (number) and wants to find out if the data is a phone number and if so who it belongs to. So the user decides to use grover's algorithm and lets say IBM's Q experience. In IBM's Q experience the user can decide which device to use (Q 5 Tenerife, Q 14 Melbourne, ...). All with different properties. How should the user decide which one to use? What does it depend on? What aspects of the given algorithm contributes to the decision?

Does anybody know some good literature or papers to read, or as a starting point ?
Or good keywords to search for? 
Should I look into compilers, even though papers in that direction never really name the attributes of the algorithms?
In which topic area do I have to look into?

I can't find much. And if there is no much research in that area, I guess it won't be possible to write a thesis about that.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
krsp.

Comment: To clarify, is the aim of this Master's thesis as a survey or original research? Because it could absolutely be possible to test a few (extraordinarily simple) algorithms across some publicly available chips